# Creating a asp:checkbox in a literal doesn't display. ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, literals

I have my literal in my html code.

```
<tbody>
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>    
</tbody>
```

In my VB code I tell it to create an asp:checkbox:

```
Protected Sub Page_LoadComplete(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.LoadComplete

Literal1.Text &= "<tr>" &
                     "<td>" & MyDataReader(0) & "</td>" &
                     "<td>" & MyDataReader(1) & "</td>" &
                     "<td>" & MyDataReader(2) & "</td>" &
                     "<td>Files Go Here</td>" &
                     "<td><asp:CheckBox ID=""CheckBox" & MyDataReader(0) & """ runat=""server"" /></td></tr>"
```

My problem is that the checkbox doesn't show up on the page after loading, everything else does. I look at the source code for the page and the asp:checkbox is there in the source in the table, but doesn't show up on the web page itself. I can put in a non asp:checkbox: `<input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" />` and it will show up. The literal is inside of `<form id="form1" runat="server">`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hello Brandon!  There is a lot more to a server side control (the <asp:stuff>) than just outputting a tag on the client side.  ASP.NET will actually output a regular <input> tag to the client and provide hooks for events on the server side.  Basically, what you are doing will not work.  Is there any reason why you can't put all that code in the aspx page and wrap it in an asp:Panel that is hidden or made visible as required?

Answer (score 1):

An `asp:checkbox` is rendered by the processor. You can't insert it like that into a literal. You can create a `new CheckBox()` and add that to a `Placeholder` control.

eg:

```
 CheckBox chk = new CheckBox()
 chk.ID = "CheckBox" + MyDataReader(0)
 placeholder.Controls.Add(chk)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding runat="server" as an attribute.

That is

```
<input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" runat="server" />
```

Also, check out this forum posting: 
http://forums.asp.net/t/1676105.aspx/1

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is your control is being added as text instead of a rendered control. ASP.NET processes the page and replaces the tags with "runat='server'" before the page is rendered. I think you're outputting text with invalid markup, thus nothing shows up.

One of the options you have available is creating your table as an ASP.NET table, then adding the control through your codebehind.

Untested code would look something like this:

```
Dim table myTable as table
Dim tableRow tr as new TableRow
Dim cell as new TableCell
cells.controls.Add(new CheckBox("values","here")) 'Pseudo code here 
tr.Cells.Add(cell)
table.Rows.Add(tr)
```

Or you can do it the easy way and add "runat=server" to your table.